# Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1

Tags: android, database-connection

Can anybody help me to solve this exception which is occurring in my code?

```
02-10 17:16:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(8619): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
```

I'm stucked in this. and should i really do care about this "Database Version" thing?

Comment: Seems like you have a good answer here.  Please accept it if correct.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you are using `Android SQLiteOpenHelper`, you need to override `onDowngrade` if you want to be able to run your application with a database on the device with a higher version than your code can handle.

You should care about this "Database Version thing" if ever your database schema is ever going to change (and in general, there is good chance it would).

Comment: about onDowngrade be aware that: If not overridden, default implementation will reject downgrade and throws SQLiteException

Comment: Normally what operations are performed in  `onDowngrade()`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Database SqliteOpenHelper constructor it's last paramter should be the same if you use more than on SQLitehelper like ORM

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change the SQLite version 1 to 2 because I had to increase the version to add a new column to my table(alter). And it's worked fine. Then, for fun I tried to change 2 to 1 like below:

From:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);}
```

To:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);}
```

Then I got this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.android.vocab, PID: 3360
                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
```

As I explained before, we cannot decrease SQLite version after increased. So you need to change back to `2` or greater than `2`:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
}
```

**If you are trying to update your table,** probably need to pass `3` not `2` and each and every time you need to update table, you need to **increase the version(not decrease)**.

If you really want to  downgrade the version you can override the `onDowngrade()`as @Matthieu expressed in his answer.