# Android SMS SQLite Crash "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 58 to 55"

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi `stackoverflow` I'm trying to get the total number of messages, but I'm getting the following exception from few users only.

And also this question has been asked in `stackoverflow` in the following link [android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 58 to 55 for android sms database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669499/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-cant-downgrade-database-from-version-5)

I'm using the following code

```
private void totalSMS()
{
    try{
        Uri allMessages = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(allMessages, null, null, null, null);
        totalMessages = 0;

        while (c.moveToNext()) 
        {
            String messageBody = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
            long messageLength = messageBody.length();
            double numberOfMessages = messageLength / 160.0;
            double numberOfMessagesRoundedUp = Math.ceil(numberOfMessages);

            totalMessages = (int) (totalMessages + numberOfMessagesRoundedUp);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        totalMessages = 0;
    }
}
```

and I'm getting following `crash` information

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from     version 58 to 55
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:184)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
```

Please help me to solve this riddle.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Chethan what exactly you are looking for conversation or a single complete thread

Comment: @sandy Thanks for your time, I'm trying to get total number of messages present in messages.

Comment: Did you test this on emulator or real device? Using what Android version (API level)? If using real device, what is the brand?

Comment: @antimo Thanks, actually I'm getting this `exception` from very few users.

Comment: My Suggestion is first fetch all conversations like "content://sms/conversations/" then one by one using thread id can fetch all msgs.

Comment: this code is working with me dude

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia It will work in most of the devices, but only few among thousand's of devices I'm getting this crash

Comment: Do you know anything from these users about what devices/SW they are on or what they had recently done prior to getting this crash? Sounds like they are loading older SW onto their device after having upgraded, which is causing the SMS database to attempt to rollback to an older version.

Comment: yeah this happens in kitkat,devices which comes with kitkat itself(not upgraded one's), because in kitkat you won't get SMS app by default, so.

Comment: Getting this error on Android L preview (from 68 to 57), but working fine on 4.4.x and any other versions below!? If it's a new security mechanism (eg only the default SMS app can read them), then the error is meaningless, will check to confirm.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with the default SMS app, just tested, made the app the default, same exception. It might relate to the SDK packaging some DB version that would result in such issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 58 to 55 for android sms database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669499/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-cant-downgrade-database-from-version-5)

Comment: @marmor Thanks for the reply, but its very old post already solved. Thanks for the support :)