# Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1 error when i run my android app

Tags: android

I found some articles with the same error but solution did not work, I tried the following:

[Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018025/cant-downgrade-database-from-version-2-to-1)

solution: `"you need to override onDowngrade"` that does not apply to my code , because my database class does not extend anything.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: If you're not using `SQLOpenHelper`, then you're pretty much on your own. Without your code, we couldn't even begin to help you.