# Sqlite - on downgrade

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Recently I updated my android game, editing sqlite database adding new field in my table, after update, I received 4 crash reports (3 of them comes from same device, Samsung Galaxy S4)

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from
>   version 2 to 1 at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:361)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:255)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)

I really can not understand what might be the reason, when it could be even possible to start downgrading database, while it actually needed to upgrade in my last database.

During update, I have obviously increased DATABASE_VERSION value from 1 to 2

I am not overriding onDowngrade method, my onUpgrade looks like following:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    updateToVersion2(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}

private void updateToVersion2(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    if (oldVersion <= 1)
    {
        ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
        cv1.put(FIELD_WORLD_ID, 6);
        cv1.put(FIELD_MAX_UNLOCKED, 1);
        db.insert(TABLE_LEVELS, null, cv1);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This method will only be called, if a device had the new version installed and upgraded the DB and now is going back to the old version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018025/cant-downgrade-database-from-version-2-to-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not overriding the `onDowngrade` method.  As explained in the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onDowngrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29), you need to, or you will get an exception:

> If not overridden, default implementation will reject downgrade and throws SQLiteException

Comment: That`s weird, so now I am wondering why it happens so rarely? My game has been downloaded like 2.500.000 times and only few problems like that occurred, than you for an answer, can you please just tell me, should I leave this method blank after overriding?

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in Samsung implementation that calls the downgrade when it should not.  You could try to implement an empty version and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Yes, you can leave this method blank. It is based on your requirement. Just make sure you are not calling `super` method from `onDowngrade`.

Comment: Yeah got the same thing with a S4 and a Note3...I have no overridden downgrade method.  Funny thing is the database it is complaining about has never gone beyond version#1 but my error message was downgrade from 11 to 1...very weird.