# Can't downgrade database from version `n` to `n-1` on Samsung

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I have an application with a database, created and opened using the standard SQLiteOpenHelper.

Whenever I upgrade the database version, I also upgrade the application's version code, so there is no way for the database to go down (the database version number is always increased, never decreased).

I disabled database backup in my app by setting the `android:allowBackup` property to false.

But when I upgrade the app on the Play Store, I get a lot of crash

> Can't downgrade database from version `n` to `n-1`

96% of those crash occur on Samsung device running . Anyone know why this problem occurs, and more importantly how to prevent this crash ?

I know that I can override the onDowngrade to prevent the crash but I actually don't understand why the onDowngrade is called at all as the crash is called on an app that always use the last version of the database.

**Edit** : Added code sample, FWIW

My OpenHelper :

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MyDBHelper.class.getName();

    public static final String DB_NAME = "my_db";
    public static final int DB_V1 = 1;
    public static final int DB_V2_UNIQUE_IDS = 2;
    public static final int DB_V3_METADATAS = 3;
    public static final int DB_V4_CORRUPTED_IDS = 4;
    public static final int DB_V5_USAGE_TABLE = 5;

    public static final int DB_VERSION = DB_V5_USAGE_TABLE;

    public MyDBHelper(final Context context, IExceptionLogger logger) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Debug.log_d(DebugConfig.DEFAULT, LOG_TAG, "onCreate()");
        db.execSQL(createMyTable());
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {
        Debug.log_d(DebugConfig.DEFAULT, LOG_TAG, "onUpgrade(): oldVersion = " + oldVersion + " : newVersion = " + newVersion);

        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            Debug.log_d(DebugConfig.DEFAULT, LOG_TAG, "onUpgrade(): upgrading version 1 table to version 2");
            db.execSQL(upgradeTable_v1_to_v2());
        }

        if (oldVersion < 3) {
            Debug.log_d(DebugConfig.DEFAULT, LOG_TAG, "onUpgrade(): upgrading version 2 Entry table to version 3");
            db.execSQL(upgradeTable_v2_to_v3());
        }
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
    public void onDowngrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {
        Debug.log_d(DebugConfig.DEFAULT, LOG_TAG, "onDowngrade(): oldVersion = " + oldVersion + " : newVersion = " + newVersion);
        super.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

And how I initialize it :

```
public class DatabaseController {

    private MyDBHelper mDBHelper;

    public void initialize(final Context context) {

       mDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(context);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to see if those crashes come from rooted devices? on rooted devices users can downgrade apps if they choose to

Comment: 99.9% of the device are not rooted.

Comment: are you maybe using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` with a version parameter somewhere in your project? If you're overriding `SQLiteOpenHelper`, make sure you're calling super in the constructor with the latest version

Comment: Nope, the SQLiteOpen helper uses a static final constant int as it's version argument. Besides, if it was the case it would crash on all kind of devices and not just on Samsungs

Comment: post your SQLiteOpenHelper class constructors, and onUpgrade methods, also, post some code on how you're using this class in some other code.

Comment: here `mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context)` you meant `mDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(context)` ?

Comment: Yes sorry... meant to anonimize / cleanup my production code but missed one

Comment: What are the reported `n`/`n-1` values? Are they plausible?

Comment: They are reported as downgrading from version 5 to 4, so basically downgrading from the current expected version to the previous version

Comment: You forgot to add the stacktrace for those crashes. This would have been a bit more obvious then.

Answer (score 9):

This is the default implementation of `SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(...)`:

```
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    throw new SQLiteException("Can't downgrade database from version " +
            oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
}
```

As you see if you call `super.onDowngrade(...)`, as you do, you'll get that exception. You need to implement `onDowngrade` yourself, without calling `super.onDowngrade`. It should always be implemented for the sake of completeness, as there's no guarantee when it might be called - it sounds strange that the user has changed to use an older version of the app but there might be a situation like that. Do you know what version of the app the exceptions come from?

Comment: This was so obvious that I didn't even notice the call to the super method... Note : The question at the end is not necessary, to downgrade a DB (for any reason), this need to be implemented, same for the upgrade.

Comment: If you had read my question, I said that I know I can override the onDowngrade method. My question was about why the onDowngrade was called for absolutely no reason !

Comment: Can you see what app version those crashes come from? That might give you some hint - if it's the latest version, the system is doing something strange.

Comment: Seems that [you're not the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786988/sqlite-on-downgrade) who's getting a strange downgrade to an earlier database version on Samsung devices only.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment in the @etan answer:

> why the onDowngrade was called for absolutely no reason?

There is absolute reason,

```
public static final int DB_V5_USAGE_TABLE = 5;

public static final int DB_VERSION = DB_V5_USAGE_TABLE;
```

your `DB_VERSION` holds `5` and in your constructor, you are passing that value. Obviously argument for version should be greater than the previous version otherwise you will get this message.

As @etan expressed, if you need to downgrade the version you need to properly override the `onDowngrade` method instead throwing the error again.

You may be knew this, so please try to remember your previous version or try to pass `6` or greater for database version parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by remove "super.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);" line or comment it

```
@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  //super.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
  Log.w(TAG, "Downgrade database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
}
```

Comment: Use for code formatting 4 spaces